# Excel Macro - Allocate a total of inputs have

Tags: excel, vba

Say that I will have a feed that will insert finite values of EUR, USD, JPY, CAD Etc.

[image: The excel screnshot]

My purpose is that every time a value of EUR or any other currency type that will be inserted, it will automatically add it to the Total.

Comment: `=SUMIF(A:A,D1,B:B)`?

Comment: ummm ...... 549?

Comment: @A.S.H "The answer to Life, the universe and everything"... no wait that's 42

Comment: @ScottCraner oops you're using the unreliable sumif. I trust sumproduct ;)

Comment: Sorry if my writing was a little confusing.
But, assume that there will be more and more rows inserted, and every row could be with any currency available. 
if I put the SUMIF, that will allocate whatever I index in it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question.  Try it and you will see.  In addition to the SUMIF, consider using SUMPRODUCT.

=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=D1),--(B:B))

[image]